# frame set on renderTexture in Cocos2D

Tags: ipad, cocos2d-iphone

I'm new to cocos2D and I want to draw lines in it, which I tried to implement from [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aS37W.png)

I've a problem with the frame set in it. I set background image by the below code

CCSprite* background = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:imgPath rect:frame];

where imgPath is the path of the image file that is set to CCSprite and frame is the view bounds. CCSprite's frame is ok and now I added

```
  [background addChild: [LineDrawingClass node]];
```

Then I added a CCRenderTexture instance to the LineDrawingClass with the following code snips

renderTexture.anchorPoint = ccp(0, 0);
renderTexture.position = ccp(self.width * 0.5f, self.height * 0.5f);

then I added renderTexture to LineDrawingClass

What I got is the CCSprite's background set to correct frame, with no problem but renderTexture's frame is set some five pixel below the CCSprite.

I also set the anchor point to

renderTexture.anchorPoint = ccp(0.5f, 0.5f);

but the lag in origin.y of renderTexture remains.

Please see the attached image for reference. Can some one point out the mistake and correct me that renderTexture's frame is exactly over the CCSprite's frame (which is now 5px lag with origin.y)??

[image]

Comment: I've heard it repeatedly that CCRenderTexture has some offset issues. From what I know this looks to be a bug in cocos2d.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the height of the texture a bit larger say if 480 is ur height, set it as 580 or greater than that could match ur requirements.

```
renderTexture.position = ccp(self.width * 0.5f, (self.height + 100) * 0.5f);
```

Its becoz of some orientation problem.